# How to add up items in check boxes in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm making a coffee shop and I have 3 items right now with prices https://gyazo.com/8944d8097223667d44095b1c5db8ceeb and I made a list box which lists the ticked boxes. Now I want to create a label or something which says "Total cost:__" and the prices added together.

Since I'm quite new to C#, I'm stuck on this. How can I add them up?

To populate the list box, I use:

```
if (TeaPrice.Checked)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("Tea £2.50");
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.Items.Remove("Tea £2.50");
        }
    }
```

I am targeting WinForms.

Comment: It should be explicitly said what kind of app you are targetting: UWP, WFP or WinForms ...

Comment: Please edit your question and at least include what type of c# project we're dealing with (i.e. WebForms, MVC, WinForms, Etc).  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am targeting WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you give more details in your questions, based on what you showed us the solution would be create an object with some properties.

```
public class Tea
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

You probably already know how to create a list of items:

```
List<Tea> items = new List<Tea>();
```

To get the total price you can use `foreach` to iterate through your list:

```
public decimal TotalPrice()
    {
        decimal sum = 0;

        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            sum += item.Price;
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

Then set you label text property like this:

```
yourLabel.Text = string.Format("Total price: {0}", TotalPrice());
```